# Sorting alphanumeric and numeric columns together

Tags: shell, sorting

I have a file wherein I need to sort the E index followed by I index such that the file, I have many such indexes not just the one mentioned below:

```
**chr3  148813677   148815677   ENSG00000071794:I1  -**
chr3    148804104   148804291   ENSG00000071794:E1  -
chr3    148804291   148804292   ENSG00000071794:E1  -
chr3    148804292   148804309   ENSG00000071794:E1  -
chr3    148804309   148804317   ENSG00000071794:E1  -
chr3    148804317   148804341   ENSG00000071794:E1  -
chr3    148802469   148802676   ENSG00000071794:E2  -
chr3    148801419   148801522   ENSG00000071794:E3  -
chr3    148793668   148793834   ENSG00000071794:E4  -
chr3    148792002   148792135   ENSG00000071794:E5  -
chr3    148791012   148791109   ENSG00000071794:E6  -
chr3    148789370   148789444   ENSG00000071794:E7  -
chr3    148802677   148804103   ENSG00000071794:I1  -
chr3    148801523   148802468   ENSG00000071794:I2  -
chr3    148793835   148801418   ENSG00000071794:I3  -
chr3    148792136   148793667   ENSG00000071794:I4  -
chr3    148791110   148792001   ENSG00000071794:I5  -
chr3    148789445   148791011   ENSG00000071794:I6  -
chr3    148789231   148789369   ENSG00000071794:I7  -
```

becomes

```
 chr3   148789231   148789369   ENSG00000071794:I7  -
 chr3   148789370   148789444   ENSG00000071794:E7  -
 chr3   148789445   148791011   ENSG00000071794:I6  -
 chr3   148791012   148791109   ENSG00000071794:E6  -
 chr3   148791110   148792001   ENSG00000071794:I5  -
 chr3   148792002   148792135   ENSG00000071794:E5  -
 chr3   148792136   148793667   ENSG00000071794:I4  -
 chr3   148793668   148793834   ENSG00000071794:E4  -
 chr3   148793835   148801418   ENSG00000071794:I3  -
 chr3   148801419   148801522   ENSG00000071794:E3  -
 chr3   148801523   148802468   ENSG00000071794:I2  -
 chr3   148802469   148802676   ENSG00000071794:E2  -
 chr3   148802677   148804103   ENSG00000071794:I1  -
 chr3   148802677   148804103   ENSG00000071794:I1  -
 chr3   148804104   148804291   ENSG00000071794:E1  -
 chr3   148804291   148804292   ENSG00000071794:E1  -
 chr3   148804292   148804309   ENSG00000071794:E1  -
 chr3   148804309   148804317   ENSG00000071794:E1  -
 chr3   148804317   148804341   ENSG00000071794:E1  -
```

By removing any duplicate IDs (in this case first row in bold) that are out of the consecutive order between columns 2 and 3 of each row. In short I want to order my rows in terms of the IDs esp everything after ':' and the positions in 2nd and 3rd columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ sort -k 4,3 my_file 

chr3    148789231   148789369   ENSG00000071794:I7  -
chr3    148789370   148789444   ENSG00000071794:E7  -
chr3    148789445   148791011   ENSG00000071794:I6  -
chr3    148791012   148791109   ENSG00000071794:E6  -
chr3    148791110   148792001   ENSG00000071794:I5  -
chr3    148792002   148792135   ENSG00000071794:E5  -
chr3    148792136   148793667   ENSG00000071794:I4  -
chr3    148793668   148793834   ENSG00000071794:E4  -
chr3    148793835   148801418   ENSG00000071794:I3  -
chr3    148801419   148801522   ENSG00000071794:E3  -
chr3    148801523   148802468   ENSG00000071794:I2  -
chr3    148802469   148802676   ENSG00000071794:E2  -
chr3    148802677   148804103   ENSG00000071794:I1  -
chr3    148804104   148804291   ENSG00000071794:E1  -
chr3    148804291   148804292   ENSG00000071794:E1  -
chr3    148804292   148804309   ENSG00000071794:E1  -
chr3    148804309   148804317   ENSG00000071794:E1  -
chr3    148804317   148804341   ENSG00000071794:E1  -
```